# Ends flushes the buffer or not

Tags: c++, io

Currently I'm self-learning C++.  
 The C++ primer says:

```
cout << "hi!" << ends; //writes hi and a null, then flushes the buffer
```

However The C++ standard library second edition says:

```
ends: Outputs '\0'
```

And the references on cplusplus also doesn't mention flush the buffer.
So which one should I follow?

Comment: Are you sure you're reading that correctly? I find it odd that C++ primer would advocate putting a null character on `cout`, are you sure it doesn't read `endl`?

Comment: @user657267 I double checked already. Exact the same thing as it appears on E-textbook

Comment: `ends` is mostly a historical artefact, what version of C++ primer are you using?

Comment: @user657267 C++ primer 5th edition

Comment: Well that's definitely wrong, either way I really don't think you'll be needing `ends` in this day and age.

Comment: @user657267 Yeah true, after looking into other book I think I should just give up reading C++ primer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### An excerpt from C++ 2011 27.7.3.8

> ```
> namespace std {
>   template <class charT, class traits>
>     basic_ostream<charT,traits>& endl(basic_ostream<charT,traits>& os);
> }
> ```
>
> Effects: Calls `os.put(os.widen(’\n’))`, then `os.flush()`. Returns: `os`.
>
> ```
> namespace std {
>   template <class charT, class traits>
>   basic_ostream<charT,traits>& ends(basic_ostream<charT,traits>& os);
> }
> ```
>
> Effects: Inserts a null character into the output sequence: calls `os.put(charT())`. Returns: `os`.

The standard is very clear that `std::endl` flushes the stream, and that `std::ends` does not.

Answer (score 2):

The standard says (§27.7.3.8):

> ```
> namespace std {
>   template <class charT, class traits>
>   basic_ostream<charT,traits>& ends(basic_ostream<charT,traits>& os);
> }
> ```
>
> *Effects:* Inserts a null character into the output sequence: calls `os.put(charT())`.

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ends) is a good reference for these sorts of things:

> Unlike [`std::endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl), this manipulator does not flush the stream.

Comment: @Des1gnWizard: It’s a game, no apologies necessary.

Comment: I have to show respect to people who spent time helping me. It does make sense to me because I always appreciate the help I received from anyone. No one owes me anything. Best wishes for 2016! :-)